# unable insert html table with multiple row to database with error Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Tags: php, jquery, html

Please advice what I am missing. When I press Submit button, error pup up as below.

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\spa315\order.php on line 106
>
> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\spa315\order.php on line 107
>
> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\spa315\order.php on line 108
>
> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\spa315\order.php on line 109

The error is come from

```
$spa_order_desc = $spa_order_desc1[$i];
$spa_order_qty = $spa_order_qty1[$i];
$spa_order_unit_prc = $spa_order_unit_prc1[$i];
$spa_order_amt = $spa_order_amt1[$i];
```

Kindly refer below for the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
        <!--Add & delete rows from table dynamically-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#addRow').click(function(){
                    var html = $('#row_template').html();
                    $('#dataTable').append(html);
                });
                $('#deleteRow').click(function(){
                    $('#dataTable .mychkbox:checked').parents('tr').remove();

                    calc_ttl();
                });
                $('#dataTable').on('change','.select-desc',function(){
                    var cur_val = $(this).val();
                    $(this).parents('tr').find('input[name="spa_order_unit_prc"]').val(cur_val);
                });
                $('#dataTable').on('keyup','input[name="spa_order_qty"]', function(){
                    var qty = +$(this).val();
                    var unit = +$(this).parents('tr').find('input[name="spa_order_unit_prc"]').val();
                    $(this).parents('tr').find('input[name="spa_order_amt"]').val(qty*unit);

                    calc_ttl();
                });
            });
        </script>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post" name="form_order">
    <p> 
        <input type="button" value="Add Treatment" id="addRow" /> 
        <input type="button" value="Remove Treatment" id="deleteRow"  /> 
    </p>

    <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>No.</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Qty</td>
            <td>Unit Price</td>
            <td>Amount</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- table row template here -->
    <table id="row_template" style="display:none">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="mychkbox" /></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <select name="spa_order_desc" id="spa_order_desc" class="select-desc">
                    <option value="">Select Treatment</option>
                    <?php
                            while($dd=mysql_fetch_array($get_tm)) {
                ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $dd['tm_unit_prc']?>"><?php echo $dd['tm_abb'] ?> - <?php echo $dd['tm_desc'] ?></option>
                <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="spa_order_qty" id="spa_order_qty" size="5">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="spa_order_unit_prc" id="spa_order_unit_prc" readonly size="10">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="spa_order_amt" id="spa_order_amt" readonly size="10">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Create">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    //including the database connection file
    include_once("config_db.php");

    //getting data from the fields
    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {

        $spa_order_desc1 = $_POST['spa_order_desc'];
        $spa_order_qty1 = $_POST['spa_order_qty'];
        $spa_order_unit_prc1 = $_POST['spa_order_unit_prc'];
        $spa_order_amt1 = $_POST['spa_order_amt'];

        for($i=0; $i < count($spa_order_desc1); $i++) {
            $spa_order_desc = $spa_order_desc1[$i];
            $spa_order_qty = $spa_order_qty1[$i];
            $spa_order_unit_prc = $spa_order_unit_prc1[$i];
            $spa_order_amt = $spa_order_amt1[$i];
        }
        //insert data to database   
        $insert_spa_o_dtl=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_spa_order_details(spa_order_desc,spa_order_qty,spa_order_unit_prc,spa_order_amt) VALUES('$spa_order_desc','$spa_order_qty','$spa_order_unit_prc','$spa_order_amt')");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Those errors means that your code is not an array. But you force it to be an array. is it you table row loop more than one using same row?? If yes, then you need to make all of your input name react as an array. Like this. name="chk[]"

Comment: @ Norlihazmey Ghazali I have tried your above mentioned comments. However, after tested, I found that my html table column for Qty, Unit Price and Amount is unable to retrieve from database table named tb_tm. Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because you are treating a plain variable as an array. Try to rename your form elements, as given below:

> "spa_order_desc" to "spa_order_desc[]"
>
> "spa_order_qty" to "spa_order_qty[]"
>
> "spa_order_unit_prc" to "spa_order_unit_prc[]"
>
> "spa_order_amt" to "spa_order_amt[]"

Also, put the insert query within the loop to insert for each of the inputs from the previous step.

```
for($i=0; $i < count($spa_order_desc1); $i++) {
    $spa_order_desc = $spa_order_desc1[$i];
    $spa_order_qty = $spa_order_qty1[$i];
    $spa_order_unit_prc = $spa_order_unit_prc1[$i];
    $spa_order_amt = $spa_order_amt1[$i];

    $insert_spa_o_dtl=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_spa_order_details(spa_order_desc,spa_order_qty,spa_order_unit_prc,spa_order_amt) VALUES('$spa_order_desc','$spa_order_qty','$spa_order_unit_prc','$spa_order_amt')");
}
```

Comment: I have tried your above mentioned comments. However, after tested, I found that my html table column for Qty, Unit Price and Amount is unable to retrieve from database table named tb_tm. Please advice. Thanks.